# Centering a ragged right text block in ConTeXt?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, context

I am trying to typeset a book of poems that I wrote in ConTeXt.

Consider the following:

```
\definehead[PoemTitle][section]
\setuphead[PoemTitle][number=no, page=yes, style=\sc]

\starttext

\PoemTitle{A Silly Whimsy}
\startlines
Some really 
poetic lines
are here
and here, these are 
deeply moving
\stoplines

\stoptext
```

This works well for breaking the lines, but the overall positioning on the page is poor, given the short nature of the lines.

I am trying to center this text block (not the line) on the page, including the `\PoemTitle` header. The centered text block needs to be able to break over pages.

I have been playing with the narrower environment (doesn't move the `\PoemTitle` header with the text block), the `\hbox` command (can't seem to implement anything useful), and the `\defineblock` and `\setupblock` commands. I haven't managed to get useful.

Any ideas?

*EDIT:*

@Will In LaTeX this gave me the desired result:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand{\PoemTitlefont}{%
\normalfont\scshape\flushleft% Remove centering from poem title
\hspace*{0.5\linewidth}\hspace*{-0.5\versewidth}}% Makes poem title flush left with body block.

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\versewidth}{Some really deep moving} 
\PlainPoemTitle
\PoemTitle{willy nilly}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]

Some really deep moving\\
lines of poetry\\
here.\\
It is all\\
so moving\\
\end{verse}


\end{document}
```

@Aditya:I would want to calculate the width of the longest line and choose an offset so that the longest line is in the middle of the text area, as in the LaTeX code above. It might be nice if the calculation of the longest line was automatic.

Comment: I do not completely understand what you mean by centering. Do you want all lines to start from a fixed offset from the left edge (as if the page had wider margins) or do you want to calculate the width of the longest line and choose an offset so that the longest line is in the middle of the text area?

Comment: I assume that you're still only interested in ConTeXt solutions?

Comment: It occurs to me that this design will cause different poems to be indented by different amounts. Which might be okay if each poem starts on a new page, but otherwise might be a bit strange. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: Yes, still interested in context solutions. and in my context file, i have set each poem to begin on a new page. i find the look to be much more balanced than just have the poems on the left margin.

Comment: @Mica: Did you really want to start _another_ bounty for this question, or did you just try to _award_ the bounty? For the latter it was late.

Comment: @Hendrik I wanted to reward the first bounty i started, but it had expired and wouldn't let me (or I'm too stuffed with turkey to figure out how), so I started another and awarded it. Either way, it doesn't really matter, I'm happy to have a few good answers to my questions.

Comment: @Mica: Your first bounty has also been awarded, but automatically, which means that only half the bounty amount was awarded. That's why it now says "+300" below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible solution:

1. Capture the contents of the environment (I use buffers)
2. Calculate the width `w` of the largest line (I use framedtext with autowidth=force)
3. Set a narrower environment with left spacing equal to `(hsize-w)/2`

In addition, I use lines so that you do not have to manually enter `\\`.

```
\defineframedtext[poemframed]
  [width=\textwidth,autowidth=force,align=flushleft,
   before=,after=,frame=off]

\definenarrower[poemnarrower]

\definelines[poemlines]
  [before={\startpoemnarrower[left]},
   after=\stoppoemnarrower,
  ]

\definebuffer[poem]

\def\stoppoem{\setups{poems:buffer}}

\startsetups poems:buffer
  \setupnarrower[poemnarrower][left=0pt]
  \setbox\scratchbox\vbox
    {\poemframed
    {\startpoemlines
       \getpoem
      \stoppoemlines}}
  \edef\poemhsize{\the\dimexpr(\hsize-\wd\scratchbox)/2\relax}
  \setupnarrower[poemnarrower][left=\poemhsize]
  \startpoemlines
    \getpoem
  \stoppoemlines
\stopsetups
```

This can be then used as

```
\starttext
\startpoem
Some really deep moving
lines of poetry
here.
It is all
so moving
\stoppoem


\startpoem
Some really deep moving, really really deep moving
lines of poetry
here.
It is all
so moving
\stoppoem
\stoptext
```

If you want, you can use other features of lines (automatic indenting of alternate lines, etc).

**EDIT** Forgot that you also wanted section titles to be middle aligned. For that add

```
\definehead[PoemTitle][section]

\setuphead[PoemTitle]
  [number=no,page=yes,style=\sc,alternative=command,command=\donothing]
```

and change `poem:buffer` to

```
\startsetups poems:buffer
  \setupnarrower[poemnarrower][left=0pt]
  \setuphead[PoemTitle][margin=0pt]
  \setbox\scratchbox\vbox
    {\poemframed[align=normal,autowidth=force]
    {\startpoemlines
       \getpoem
      \stoppoemlines}}
  \edef\poemhsize{\the\dimexpr(\hsize-\wd\scratchbox)/2\relax}
  \setuphead[PoemTitle][margin=\poemhsize]
  \setupnarrower[poemnarrower][left=\poemhsize]
  \startpoemlines
    \getpoem
  \stoppoemlines
\stopsetups
```

Comment: Looks good. This would be the same approach I'd use in LaTeX. (I.e., setting and measuring before setting on the page with appropriate paragraph settings.)

Comment: This will fail if the content is somewhat sophisticated (automatic counters, etc). TSo, the measuring phase should have `\settrialtypesetting` (in MkIV) and `\trialtypesettingtrue` (in MkII).  I wonder if luatex makes such things easier: in principle one could create a node list, measure the max width, and move it around using attributes.

Comment: Sorry, I have been without a working computer for a few days. I will test this over the weekend. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

Obligatory LaTeX example `:)` I know the question specifies a ConTeXt solution, but it's good to cross-pollinate ideas.

Since Aditya queried the intended output in the comments, here's how I interpret what the question is looking for: (I haven't attempted to replicate the proper markup for creating the poem title or anything, though)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\obeylines
\textsc{A Silly Whimsy}
Some really 
poetic lines
are here
and here, these are 
deeply moving
\end{varwidth}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for a LaTeX solution :) But the OP wanted an environment that splits across pages, and `varwidth` is built on top of `minipage` so won't break across a page.

Comment: @Aditya — Ah, in that case I'd use Mica's solution but typeset the whole poem in a box first to pre-calculate the maximum line width.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Will's answer, this is how you can do the same in ConTeXt. This uses framedtexts, so will not break across pages.

First, to center align the head, just add `alternative=middle` to `\setuphead`

To center the contents first define

```
\defineframedtext[poemframed]
                 [width=\textwidth,
                  autowidth=force,
                  align=flushleft,
                  before=,
                  after=,
                  frame=off]
```

This is equivalent to the `varwidth` environment in LaTeX. Basically, `autowidth=force` forces the width of the box to equal the length of the largest line.

Next, we plug in this framedtext to a poems environment that obeys the lines.

```
\definelines[poem]
            [before={\startpoemframed[middle]},
             after=\stoppoemframed]
```

The `middle` in `\startpoemframed[middle]` ensures that the box is middle aligned. Now you can use

```
\startpoem
...
\stoppoem
```

to get middle aligned, left flushed, lines. As I said earlier, this will not break across pages. I don't know an easy way to ensure that the contents break across pages.

Answer (score 2):

If it is not a problem to figure out the widest line manually, then a much shorter solution is possible:

```
\def\startpoem[#1]%
  {\begingroup 
   \setbox0\hbox{#1}%
   \setupnarrower[left=\dimexpr (\the\hsize-\the\wd0)/2\relax]%
   \startnarrower[left]%
   \startlines}

\def\stoppoem
   {\stoplines
    \stopnarrower
    \endgroup}
```

But then of course you need

```
\startpoem[and here, these are]
```

Comment: I have been without a working computer for a few days. I will try this over the weekend. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: @Mica: Don't forget to award the bounty within the next 8 hours (if possible)!

Answer (score 1):

To add another latex solution (which perhaps triggers ideas in the context users): Use longtable

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,longtable}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{longtable}{l}
\large\bfseries Title \\*[1ex]
 line 1\\
 line 2\\
 line 3 a bit longer
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```