# Make a ragged-right text block flushright in Context

Tags: horizontal-alignment, context

I am trying to flush right a ragged-right text block in ConTeXt. Somewhat similar to a signature block in a letter; its longest line should flush right, while other shorter lines align themselves with its left. I tried the solution given in [Centering a ragged right text block in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5384/centering-a-ragged-right-text-block-in-context), changing the width `size-\wd\scratchbox)/2` to `\hsize-\wd\scratchbox)`, but the whole text block does not flush right.

MWE

```
\defineframedtext[sigblockframed]
  [width=\textwidth,autowidth=force,align=flushleft,
   before=,after=,frame=off]

\definenarrower[sigblocknarrower]
\definelines[sigblocklines]
  [before={\startsigblocknarrower[left]},
   after=\stopsigblocknarrower,
  ]

\definebuffer[sigblock]
\def\stopsigblock{\setups{sigblock:buffer}}

\startsetups sigblock:buffer
  \setupnarrower[sigblocknarrower][left=0pt]
  \setbox\scratchbox\vbox
    {\sigblockframed
    {\startsigblocklines
       \getsigblock
      \stopsigblocklines}}
  \edef\sigblockhsize{\the\dimexpr(\hsize-\wd\scratchbox)\relax}
  \setupnarrower[sigblocknarrower][left=\sigblockhsize]
  \startsigblocklines
    \getsigblock
  \stopsigblocklines
\stopsetups
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `\hfill` will work:

```
\definestartstop
  [signature]
  [
    before={\endgraf\blank\hfill\signatureframed\bgroup},
    after={\removeunwantedspaces\egroup},
  ]
\defineframed
  [signatureframed]
  [
    align=flushleft,
    frame=off,
    offset=overlay,
  ]

\starttext
\input knuth

\startsignature
  Don Knuth \\
  The first \TEX\ user
\stopsignature

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 2):

While you can use *primitives* like `\hfill` to align the framed block to the right ConTeXt already provides a command for this. With `\rightaligned` the argument of the command is pushed to the right side and when you need it in an environment you use the `\startrightaligned` command.

```
\definestartstop
  [signature]
  [before={\blank\startrightaligned\startframed[signatureframed]},
    after={\stopframed\stoprightaligned}]

\defineframed
  [signatureframed]
  [ width=fit,
    align=flushleft,
    frame=off,
   offset=overlay]

\starttext

\input knuth

\startsignature
  Don Knuth \\
  The first \TEX\ user
\stopsignature

\stoptext
```

Another way to achieve the same output is to use the `framedtext` environment which let you align the whole block to either the *left* or *right* side of the text block with the first optional argument.

```
\definestartstop
  [signature]
  [before={\startsignatureframed[right]},
    after={\stopsignatureframed}]

\defineframedtext
  [signatureframed]
  [ width=fit,
    align=flushleft,
    frame=off,
   offset=overlay]

\starttext

\input knuth

\startsignature
  Don Knuth \\
  The first \TEX\ user
\stopsignature

\stoptext
```